# making changes to static files served by exrepss.static that still have maxAge affect

Tags: node.js, express

i have tried to find a solution but all the answers led me to things i couldn't implement or understand.

i have a express node.js script that serves my static application files:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'app'), { maxAge: 30000}));
```

i want to set the maxAge to lets say 1 week.

as my application will be going to production soon i am supposed to have frequent changes to my files which will cause changes on daily basis.

how would i be able to tell the browsers that i need it to download a new version of the files?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the use of [asset rack](https://github.com/techpines/asset-rack) so that you can include special versions of all of your static files which include a fingerprint. Then, when you update any of the files, the fingerprint changes, and the browser will download the new version.